# how to make magit respect the current window layout

Tags: emacs, magit

Suppose I have a vertical split in the current frame where I have two windows, left and right. Now I invoke `M-x magit-status` in the left window.

- what happens: magit takes over the whole frame
- what I'd like to happen: magit should take over only the left window from where I originally invoked `M-x magit-status`.

how do I achieve the desired behaviour? Is it even Possible?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magit doesn't do this by default. You are probably using a starter-kit, Spacemacs maybe?

This is controlled using the option `magit-display-buffer-function`. Check out its documentation.

Comment: thank you @tarsius, you are right, spacemacs. But I have tested with my own configuration too and the default behaviour is slightly not what I described either: if you're on the left window and invoke `M-x magit-status`, magit takes over the *right* window. You have to set this to achieve my described desired operation: `(setq magit-display-buffer-function #'magit-display-buffer-same-window-except-diff-v1)`